# My HTML table is with pagination, and I want to download the whole table rather than the current visiable rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-templates

Am new to exporting html table to csv. The code below could export only the current visible page, but I want to be able to download from pages 1 -- 200 for instance at a click of a button.

```js
// download html table to csv file
function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
  var csvFile;
  var downloadLink;

  csvFile = new Blob([csv], {
    type: "text/csv"
  });

  downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = filename;
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

  downloadLink.style.display = "none";

  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  downloadLink.click();
}

function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
  var csv = [];
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = [],
      cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
      row.push(cols[j].innerText);

    csv.push(row.join(","));
  }
  //download csv file
  downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);

}
```

Comment: How the pagination works? client? server?

Comment: Hi Mosh the pagination works from client side.

Comment: So you can display all the rows for a moment, generate the csv and hide them again. Or re-generate the table but without pagination and export it. Show me the code that generate the table..

Comment: I don't know whether you have come across this issue before. Somehow I don't know why my next or previous button for my table is not doing anything. The result still remains the same allthrough and there is no changes. For example when I search so many genes, lets say up to 100 pages, when I click next page the result is the same as the previous all through the 100 pages. Please help me out.

Comment: Table in search.html ```<table id="example1" border="1" style="background-color:#FFFFCC" width="0%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
<thead> 
<tbody>
<tr>
<th width="210px"> header1</th> 
<th width="600px"> header2 </th> 

</tr> 
</thead>
</tbody>
</table> 
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped ">
<thead> 
<tbody>
<td width="200px" "{{result.object.get_absolute_url}}">{{result.object.item1}}</td> 
<td width="450px">{{result.object.item2}}</td>
{% if result.object.item1 %}
<td width="250px"><em> D </em></td>

{% endif %}
</tbody>
</thead>
</table> 
```

Comment: What is an angular app?