# Is it possible create export as CSV button when there is pagination in your HTML using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django, export-to-csv

I am able to download the content on the current page but not able to download all the content coming to the table from the backend.

```
// Quick and simple export target #table_id into a csv
function download_as_csv(table_id, separator = ',') {
    // Select rows from table_id
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table#' + table_id + ' tr');
    // Construct csv
    var csv = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td, th');
        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
            // Clean innertext to remove multiple spaces and jumpline (break csv)
            var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ')
            // Escape double-quote with double-double-quote (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv)
            data = data.replace(/"/g, '""');
            // Push escaped string
            row.push('"' + data + '"');
        }
        csv.push(row.join(separator));
    }
    var csv_string = csv.join('\n');
    // Download it
    var filename = 'export_' + table_id + '_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '.csv';
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.style.display = 'none';
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv_string));
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

I have hound similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260013/my-html-table-is-with-pagination-and-i-want-to-download-the-whole-table-rather) with no answer.

For the backend, I am using Django and to render a table using Vue.js.Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

TIA.